# Iterate a deserealized .Net Object from Json to create a DataTable

Tags: json, vb.net, object, service

I've being spending a lot of time  thinking about how to iterate an object from a deserealized json which has many items, subitems and sub-subitems. I know there are a lot of questions already posted, but I still don't get it, 'cause the examples are differrents to mine and I'm a begineer developper. I get the Json from a Web Service and I pass the Token by headers and all that stuff, but I don't know the best way to manipulate this info. I'm using Newtonsoft library, BTW.

The Json is:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "customer": {
        "id": "string",
        "externalId": "string",
        "firstName": "string",
        "lastName": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "companyName": "string",
        "emailAddresses": [
          "string"
        ],
        "phones": [
          {
            "type": "Mobile",
            "number": "string"
          }
        ],
        "addresses": [
          {
            "lines": [
              "string"
            ],
            "locality": [
              "string"
            ],
            "region": "string",
            "postcode": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      "vehicles": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "vin": "string",
          "odometer": 0,
          "tag": "string",
          "nextServiceDue": "2015-07-14T10:08:15Z",
          "registrationTestDue": "2015-07-14T10:08:15Z",
          "brand": "string",
          "extendedWarrantyEndDate": 0,
          "contractEndDate": 0,
          "transmissionCode": "string",
          "engineCode": "string",
          "bodyType": "string",
          "paintCode": "string",
          "modelCode": "string",
          "references": [
            {
              "key": "string",
              "value": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "employees": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "name": "string",
          "type": "Technician"
        }
      ],
      "operations": [
        {
          "id": "35955",
          "code": "RWB",
          "externalCode": "RACS",
          "description": "431151: Front Shock Absorber Assembly (One Side), Repair/Replace",
          "isNew": true,
          "labour": {
            "pricing": {
              "totals": {
                "total": 0
              }
            },
            "times": [
              {
                "quantity": 1.2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "parts": [
        {
          "number": "string",
          "quantity": 1,
          "quantityUnitOfMeasure": "Hour",
          "description": "string",
          "vehicleId": "string",
          "pricing": {
            "totals": {
              "total": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "page": 0,
    "morePages": true,
    "resultCount": 0,
    "pageCount": 0
  }
}
```

And the Code for getting the json properties is:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property orders() As Order
    Public Property paging As Paging
End Class

Public Class Paging
    Public Property page As Integer
    Public Property morePages As Boolean
    Public Property resultCount As Integer
    Public Property pageCount As Integer
End Class

Public Class Order
    Public Property customer As Customer
    Public Property vehicles() As Vehicle
    Public Property employees() As Employee
    Public Property operations() As Operation
    Public Property parts() As Part
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property externalId As String
    Public Property firstName As String
    Public Property lastName As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property companyName As String
    Public Property emailAddresses() As String
    Public Property phones() As Phone
    Public Property addresses() As Address
End Class

Public Class Phone
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property number As String
End Class

Public Class Address
    Public Property lines() As String
    Public Property locality() As String
    Public Property region As String
    Public Property postcode As String
End Class

Public Class Vehicle
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property vin As String
    Public Property odometer As Integer
    Public Property tag As String
    Public Property nextServiceDue As Date
    Public Property registrationTestDue As Date
    Public Property brand As String
    Public Property extendedWarrantyEndDate As Integer
    Public Property contractEndDate As Integer
    Public Property transmissionCode As String
    Public Property engineCode As String
    Public Property bodyType As String
    Public Property paintCode As String
    Public Property modelCode As String
    Public Property references() As Reference
End Class

Public Class Reference
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property value As String
End Class

Public Class Employee
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property type As String
End Class

Public Class Operation
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property code As String
    Public Property externalCode As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property isNew As Boolean
    Public Property labour As Labour
End Class

Public Class Labour
    Public Property pricing As Pricing
    Public Property times() As Time
End Class

Public Class Pricing
    Public Property totals As Totals
End Class

Public Class Totals
    Public Property total As Integer
End Class

Public Class Time
    Public Property quantity As Single
End Class

Public Class Part
    Public Property number As String
    Public Property quantity As Integer
    Public Property quantityUnitOfMeasure As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property vehicleId As String
    Public Property pricing As Pricing1
End Class

Public Class Pricing1
    Public Property totals As Totals1
End Class

Public Class Totals1
    Public Property total As Integer
End Class
```

And I deserealize the Json and i've traying this, an example:

```
            Dim JsonObject As List(Of Rootobject) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Rootobject))(_JsonString)

        For Each item In JsonObject
            _PagPage = item.paging.page
            _PagMorePag = item.paging.morePages
            _PagResCount = item.paging.resultCount
            _PagPagCount = item.paging.pageCount
        Next
```

I tried to use Lists like `List(Of Rootobject)` or `List(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of Rootoobject))`, but it's still not working.

If you could to help me out i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal - why does it need to be in a DataTable?  There is a fair amount to 'flatten out' in those classes

Comment: I was thinking to create a tmp table with the data of every row, I mean, all the information is about a customer who has a vehicle, etc, so, I want to stock the information acording to every customer, for example:

`Customer_Id | Customer_externalId | Vehicle_Id |`

I need that information to make my own queries and to get the specific info. I need.

Comment: You dont need to put it in a DataTable to query it - you can do that with the deserialized object. Is it destined for a database?  In that case, it looks like it wouild be several tables: Orders, Customer, Vehicle, Operation and Parts.  Those one line calsses could be removed to simplify things

Comment: Okay, I got your point, thank you, I thought I had to stock the info first before I could query it. My problem is, how to loop all the  json properties and make a class for any other classe to get the information from this one.

Comment: When you deserialize, it puts the data in perfectly good, usable classes and collections - the ones you show.  You can use linq to query, group, count, and search  the data very easily

Comment: If I want to get all the information it would be:

`Dim JsonObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(_JsonString)`

Then, to access into every propery  `JsonObject.Customer.Id`

But If it contains many rows, for example 2 customers, Do I need to itarate and stock that information? will I need some variables or arrays to get it?

Comment: Thank you! I just got it...

[NewtonSoftLibraryLINQtoJSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: All you need is the NET linq capabilities.  Once it is deserialized, it is a common ordinary NET object.  How to query it to get stuff is well outside the scope of this question (datatables)

Comment: Thank you so much...I've still having problems to iterate and to organize all the info but I'm working on it with the LINQ library. All is about learning how to use Newtonsoft, which is difficult 'cause  there are lot of ways to do it, but as I said "all I need to do is trying"